# Elixir: run an application from the parent directory

Tags: elixir

I have a root directory and several elixir applications inside it. Is there a way to: `mix run --no-halt` some of the applications from the root directory, not the application dir?

```
my_root_dir
|
├── my_first_app
|
├── my_second_app
```

Comment: The question is why would you want to in the first place?

Comment: I would echo the why would you need this in the first place. If it is because you expect the current working directory to be on a certain location, it means you are relying on relative paths and that's usually a no-no. Functions like Application.app_dir are supposed to help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `MIX_EXS` variable to point to a `mix.exs` file.  For your case it is probably something like:

```
MIX_EXS=my_root_dir/my_first_app/mix.exs mix run --no-halt
```